# Battery powered Shotgun Mic for use with PCM d-50

Tags: pcm-d50, shotgun, location, recording

I'm looking for a decent shotugn mic for field recording but I'm not sure I want to go down the broadcast mixer route just yet. Does anyone have any experience of using shotgun mic's with one of these sony pcm-d50 portables?

Essentially, it would be really handy to be able to plug a shotgun mic in to the 3.5mm jack and make some useable recordings, that's a pretty light rig..

Nick

Comment: Good question, I've been debating the same for my PCM-M10.

Answer (score 5):

I have a [Rode NTG-2](http://www.rodemic.com/microphone.php?product=NTG-2). It works fine (20hz-20khz), can be powered with an AA battery, can be connected to the 3.5mm jack and doesn't cost too much.

Comment: +1. Not the world's best shotgun, but totally functional, lightweight, cheap, and I've used one in the field a lot with zero problems.

Comment: Sound good? How do the PCM-50 preamps hold up?

Comment: Would you have any tunes available on soundcloud recorded with a D-50 + NTG-2?

Comment: +1 . rode ntg-2 will get you basic shotgun sound. i don't think you're going to write home about it, but just watch how fast it's going to earn for a new one :)

Answer (score 3):

You could have a look into the Sennheiser ME66+K6 module (make sure you don't get K6P as that's phantom powered only). I haven't tried it  myself but at least that's a decent spec shotgun that can run on batteries.

Comment: I'll second the ME66/K6 combo.  I have the NTG-2 as well as the AT835.  Both sound nice and are study and reliable.  But the ME66 is a sonic improvement. Enough to justify the price hike.  Plus you can purchase additional capsules for the K6. The onmi has come in handy a few times.

Comment: The ME66 is widely available on eBay as well, very easy to pick up a good deal for it with a minimum amount of patience.

Comment: I have a ME66, and Im not very satisfied with anything about it really. I find it to be a bit too noisy for my taste, and harsh sounding.
I would go for the Røde stuff, or spend some more money, and get a 416 and the XL1 adaptor box for the Sony recorder.

Comment: @Mikkel, that's strange what you say about the noise. These have extremely low self-noise (10dB-A). About the sound though... yeah... I'd agree with that, although that's just based on recordings I've heard. I haven't used it myself - when I was looking for a shotgun I opted for the NTG-3 instead, although that's of no use for this thread.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for the RODE NTG-2, i also use it together with my PCM-D50. it works great for sfx recording and voiceovers.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give the NTG 2 a go next month, get some field recording down and let you know how I get on :) Cheers all.

Answer (score 0):

The D50 is a great recorder but how are you syncing to picture ? if you don't sync to video you probably don't need a shot gun I use the D50 with NY4 and NT 3 and it is fantastic. David  http://www.freshcutsoundeffects.com

Comment: No sync, just for directionality when recording fx for archival really. I'm liking the look of the ntg-2 though, could be tempted when I get a windfall.
